# how to take backup of only roles/users in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I am trying to restore the backup of the database but it's giving me the error of roles, so I got to know that first, we have to take backup of roles/users then we take complete backup but I am unaware of command that can be used. can anyone help me with the command?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `pg_dumpall` for that with the `--globals-only` option:

```
pg_dumpall --globals-only --file=all_roles_and_users.sql -p postgres -h ...
```

The file `all_roles_and_users.sql` will contain all roles and role memberships currently defined in the instance (aka "cluster") you connect to.

This nee